# Spring Boot Security Angular 6

Tags: spring-boot, angular6, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to get past a 401 error unless I give full access to the website. I have built an Angular 6 app with a client side login page and have copied the results to my spring boot static folder. The app works exactly as I want - stays on login page until credentials have been verified by the server. The problem is anyone can get at my other REST resources without using the app because of the global permission. When I try and use different matchers I start getting 401 errors on all the angular files (eg. vendor.js favicon.ico...)

This is what I am currently using in my basic authentication config class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

Anybody have an example of a config that I could use or offer any assistance that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's because everything is in spring boot's static folder, if I use the following matcher everything seemed to work:

```
    .antMatchers("/*.*","/assets/**","/").permitAll()
```

On a related note, my spring boot console is complaining that it can't find public/index.html (because it's there as static/index.html). I'll look at how to tell spring boot to look there.